# MAAS + Pods - Automatic NICs config guest side

Tags: networking, virtualization, maas, kvm-virtualization

Is there a way to configure automatically the NICs that a VM has after being spawn up via the PODs?
I need serveral network interfaces for each VM I spin up via the PODs and would like to know if any MAAS configuration that allows to specify which nics and to what physical interface on the hypervisor are bridged to.

If not possible via MAAS, is there any libvirt / KVM way to achieve so, without touching by hand each configuration of each VM I spin up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MaaS Pods are not designed with that flexibility and I have not seen any other evidence of that kind of feature in development (yet).

MaaS Will pick up a network one of 3 ways in the following order:

1. Look for and attach guest to a network bridge called `maas`.
2. Look for and attach guest to a network bridge called `default`.
3. If neither the `maas` & nor `default` network are found, select first network found in alphabetical order.

Personally I have to have a `maas` network on all `libvirt` nodes. I use `openvswitch` bridges instead of the `libvirt` network defaults and connect them across hosts for a virtual overlay network. After that, you can add nic's to the networks you need for each VM while retaining maas functionality on its own virtual network.

You can check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1697108) for reference.